# Symfony 2 - Service dynamic imports

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I have **parameters** defined as:

```
parameters:
    config1:
        title: Title 1
        data_proc: getDataOne
        options: [things, stuff]
    config2:
        title: Title 2
        data_proc: getDataTwo
        options: [things, stuff]
#...
```

A **service** defined as

```
my_service:
    class: Me\MyBundle\Services\MyService
    arguments:
        - @security.context
        - @doctrine.dbal.my_connection
        - %config% # the parameter that I'd like to be dynamic
```

**controllers** like

```
class ProduitController extends Controller
{
    public function list1Action()
    {
        $ssrs = $this->get('my_service'); // with config1 params
        # ...
    }
    public function list2Action()
    {
        $ssrs = $this->get('my_service'); // with config2 params
        # ...
    }
    #...
}
```

Several controllers using `my_service`.
My `list1Action()` should call `my_service` by injecting only `config1` parameters

How can I do that without having to define as many services as controllers ?

Comment: Which service do you have? Into which controller do you try to inject? Please, bring more light on your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Me\MyBundle\Services\MyService` you could define public method, which will set new parameters (`setParameters($parameters)` for example). Then in your controller you could do this:

```
class ProduitController extends Controller
{
    public function list1Action()
    {
        $config = $this->container->getParameter('config1');
        $ssrs = $this->get('my_service')->setParameters($config);
    }

    public function list2Action()
    {
        $config = $this->container->getParameter('config2');
        $ssrs = $this->get('my_service')->setParameters($config);
    }
}
```

This would be an optimal solution.

Of course, you could override some core Classes and achieve automatic injection with number part incremented, but is it really worth of the time it might cost?

Comment: Might not. That's kind of what I'm doing now, but it does not allow to make initializations in the constructor :( So I make them in the called function.

Answer (score 2):

Define two services with different arguments but the same class and get one or the other

Comment: I use it at leact 10 times. Isn't there a way to factorize it because I end up having to repeat re-injecting some other classes again and again.